# mongodb - database is not connecting

Tags: windows, mongodb

I follow exactly the steps described in official tutorial http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Quickstart+Windows

But when I run application requiring mongodb, the error says "can not connecting to mongo".

greatly appreciate detail steps of how to run one of those mentioned apps in windows.

What I've got so far:

```
cygwin
node version 0.5 pre
npm version 3.2
mogoose installed
mongo-connect installed
jade installed
express installed
stylus installed
```

Comment: can you go to the folder where mongo is installed and run /bin/mongo .. and see if it connects to the server. This way we can know whether its an issue with the app or the server

Comment: @nEEbz: I followed the steps in the official tutorial, from what I can see, the tut only teaches me to create a directory c:/data/db. So can you teach me how to install and run /bin/mongo?

Comment: oh I see what you meant, you mean the un-ziped folder downloaded from mongo website and staying in my desktop? it has a bin folder and inside it has a bunch of files including mongo and mongod. When I run mongod, it "says connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:61910" And when I run mongo.exe it says "connecting to: test"

Comment: run mongod .. and keep it running (thats the server) ..now run mongo.exe ..does it connect and opens up a shell  where you can type commands ?

Comment: @nEEbz yes mongo.exe will open up a shell where I can type command. The first starting line of mongo.exe is "mongDb Shell version 1.8.1 " and the second line is "connecting to : test"

Comment: I've made the screen shots http://www.vietnamlist.net/pic/2772941013027223621176890_full.png and http://www.vietnamlist.net/pic/4192291013027223627060150_full.png

Comment: Congrats, this means your Mongo server is working good. Now you need to show me your connection code. There is something wrong with that :)

Comment: @nEEbz I think this is problem I'm facing, what's the connection code? Where can i get it?

Comment: can you tell me which application you are trying to run which requires MongoDB ?

Comment: @nEEbz https://github.com/gregstewart/chat.io

Comment: ok do this now > shut down the mongo server you ran initially. Go to the mongofolder/bin/ .. and run this `./mongo --bind-ip 127.0.0.1` and then run the application. it should work now.

Comment: @nEEbz I still have the same error, check out the screenshot http://www.vietnamlist.net/pic/8911391013027620709103360_full.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the following as it is:

1. Open Command line prompt in Windows
2. Goto your mongodb directory (~/mongodb/bin/) and run the following command:

   `./mongo --bind_ip localhost:27017`

   Now it will give you the message that mongo server is running and waiting connections at port 27017.
3. Now make sure that you keep this window running and **open a new windows command line window** and run the chat.io using the same `node main.js` command

This SHOULD work. Everything seems set now !

Comment: change it to `mongo --bind_ip localhost:27017`

Comment: for anyone has the same problem and this answer doesn't work for you, you can check out other solution here https://github.com/gregstewart/chat.io/issues/1

Comment: localhost not linking up to 127.0.0.1 ..that's a new issue. glad to hear you got it solved. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the mongo service isn't starting.  Did you create some method (such as a batch file, or windows service) that will launch the mongo db?